# Query for specific files from GraphCMS Assets using GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, graphcms

I'm using GraphCMS as my CMS for my GatsbyJS site, and I want to query for a specific image files, which I can then use in a React component.

When using localhost:8000___grapql I'm able to find all my assets using this path:

```js
{
  discord: allGraphCmsAsset(filter: {fileName: {eq: "discord_community.png"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        localFile { 
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 600) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my my React component file named community.tsx, I'm trying to render the discord image defined in the query, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

```js
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import styled from "styled-components"

export default function CommunityPage({ allGraphCmsAsset }) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Img
          fluid={allGraphCmsAsset.discord.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid}
          fadeIn={false}
      />
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

export const imageQuery = graphql`
{
  discord: allGraphCmsAsset(filter: {fileName: {eq: "discord_community.png"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        localFile { 
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 600) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

const Wrapper = styled.div``
```

What should I type in curley brackets where it currently says?:

```js
fluid={allGraphCmsAsset.discord.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid}
```

Comment: check in `localhost:8000___grapql` if you can use some filter on `allGraphCmsAsset`, e.g. `allGraphCmsAsset(where:...) { `

Comment: Cool, it seems to be one part of the equation. How do I then use  that query to get my image into my react component?

Comment: test it in playground and use in `pageQuery`?

Comment: I've updated my question in the original post. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: you MUST use `pageQuery` const name!! ... you can `console.log( allGraphCmsAsset )` in component before return ... to check it's structure (very basic js question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are finding in the `localhost:8000/___graphql`, are the nodes that Gatsby and GraphQL have created using the valid filesystem/CMS configuration placed in the `gatsby-config.js`.

Once you set the configuration files like:

```
// gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-graphcms',
      options: {
        endpoint: process.env.GRAPHCMS_ENDPOINT,
        downloadLocalImages: true, // recommended to safe build times and improve SEO
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

You will be able to:

```
{
  allGraphCmsAsset {
    nodes {
      localFile {
        childImageSharp {
          fixed {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For further details check the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-graphcms/).

Your data, once the query is done, is inside `props.data.queryName`. In your case, your need to change it to:

```
export default function CommunityPage({ data }) {

console.log (data.discord) //<-- Here's your data 
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Img
          fluid={data.discord.nodes[0].localFile.childImageSharp.fluid}
          fadeIn={false}
      />
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have edited the original post now. Perhaps you can help we in what I'm doing wrong when I'm trying to render my image?

Comment: Your data is inside `props.data.discord`. In your case, since you are destructuring, `data.discord`

Comment: When changing it it gives me the following error message on localhost: 

TypeError: can't access property 0, data.discord.nodes is undefined

Comment: Well, that's why there's the console.log above, is for you to get the proper nested objets